# Getting Dates only less than a particular date using date functions

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have a table called `tableA` with `TrasactionDate` as one field. I have a particular date called `myfixeddate` (say it's `2014-03-08`).

I want to get the `TransactionDate` within 4 months, but only before my fixed date `myfixeddate` (`'2014-03-08'`) from the `tableA`. Say my query should give `'2014-03-06','2014-03-05','2014-02-01',...`.

But when I use the following query :

```
SELECT TrasactionDate 
FROM tableA 
WHERE datediff(mm,Transdate,myfixeddate) < 4
```

It gives the `TransactionDate` in both ways (before and after). That means the result gave `'2014-03-10','2014-03-18'` with the wanted ones like `'2014-03-05',...`.

Could you please tell me how to prevent this and what code I need to use to get the `TransactionDate` in one direction?

Answer (score 1):

You may try like this:

```
Select TrasactionDate from tableA 
where [TrasactionDate] between DATEADD(month, -4, myfixeddate) and myfixeddate
```